# UPDATE sql to change time only in datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-update

I want to `UPDATE` time only from `datetime` using `sql` but it seem cant work. the update will get from user and only change the time. 
example `2018-10-06 08:00:00 update to 2018-10-06 12:00:00` (time that user enter)

```
$sql3="UPDATE course 
           SET date_start = '$date_start' 
           WHERE date_start = SUBSTRING(date_start,11,17)
           AND CourseNo = '$id1' ";
    $hasil3=mysql_query($sql3);

    if($hasil3==false)
        echo "SQL error:".mysql_error();
    else
    {
        ?>  <center>
    <script language="javascript"> 
            alert("Successfully update!");window.location="studentTimetable.php";
    </script>
```

Comment: what is your DMBS, sql server or mysql or plsql , have you made any attempt using `dateadd`

Comment: So you want to add 4 hours? To all rows?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: You can find solution here : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp

Comment: i am using mysql. not yet attempt using dateadd because i dont know how to use. the data should change based on user prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression such as:

```
select date('2018-10-06 08:00:00') + interval 12 hour
```

You can also use `addtime()` if you want to add hours/minutes/seconds.

This should be simple enough to put into an `update` statement if that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you get an input as string in the format `<hours> ":" <minutes> ":" <seconds>`, that represents a time of the day. You want to replace the time of the day portion of a `datetime` column with that given time of the day.

To do so you can first downcast the column to a `date` and then upcast it again to a `datetime`. That way the time of the day portion becomes 00:00:00. Now use `date_add` to add the time of the day the user has given to you. Since the time of the day was zeroed before that will result in a `datetime` with the time of the day as the user put in.

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET nmuloc = date_add(cast(cast(nmuloc AS date) AS datetime), INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR_SECOND);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this..

I have a number of dates that are not quite right by a few seconds.  They should all end on an Hour, i.e 00:00

1. Work out how much time I need add (I know i want to add some seconds)

```
SELECT 60 - DATEPART(SECOND, EndDate), e.*
FROM   Events e 
WHERE  DatePart(SECOND, EndDate) <> 0
```

2. Now I can write an update to correct all the dates that are slightly off.

```
UPDATE Events 
SET EndDate = DATEADD(SECOND, i.Seconds, i.EndDate)  
FROM (
    SELECT Id, 60 - DATEPART(SECOND, EndDate) AS Seconds, EndDate
    FROM Events e 
    WHERE  DatePart(SECOND, EndDate) <> 0
) i
WHERE 
    i.ID = Events.ID
```